# Can a Spring bean be a property of itself in its declaration in applicationContext.xml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I need to call public methods of the `rubberStampService` from inside the `RubberStampServiceImpl` class.

To reference the `rubberStampService` from inside itself, can I make a self-referential bean declaration like this:

```
<beans:bean id="rubberStampService" class="com.rubberly.RubberStampServiceImpl">
    <beans:property name="rubberStampService" ref="rubberStampService" />
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: what's the purpose? Working with aspects around the bean? Injecting a prototype (new instance) bean? Or simply calling own methods?

Comment: You may need this to leverage proxied enchancment as @Async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an infinitely recursive, out of memory error waiting to happen.  Why not just have the service call its own method and be done with it?  You don't need a new reference, just "this".

```
public interface FooService()
{
    void foo();
    void bar();
}

public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService
{
    public void foo() { System.out.println("calling foo"); }
    public void bar()
    {
        this.foo(); // just call your own method.
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to recursively call the same method, you can allways call other method...

Comment: Because you have wrong assumptions - sometimes this just ins't the right answer

Comment: "Sometimes" - so maybe you're the one making assumptions.  And you'll concede that it is correct sometimes.  So why the downvote, two years later?  Don't you have anything better to do?  Where's your answer?  Put in a better one and we'll see if I downvote your idea.

Comment: I was saerching answear for exactly the same question. "Can a Spring bean be a property of itself in its declaration" and this is not the answear, hope you're not so much touched by -2 points

Comment: Not the answer?  So what's your solution?

Comment: So far I have found only hacks and workarounds, that are not nice so I ended up with my service seperated into two beans

Comment: Sounds like a better answer to me.  I'll be watching to see what you have to offer her in the future.

Comment: There are reasons this might not be the solution: You might need the proxied version of the method (e.g. `@Transactional`, `@Profiled`, etc.). This was the problem I had when finding this question. Or you might have some uses of your bean where a different bean is injected, and some uses where you want to inject the same one.

Answer (score 5):

Can't see any problems with this approach.

Spring can handle circular dependencies (if they are resolveable, i.e. if you don't use constructor injection), including the case of self-referencing bean. The only difference is that in the case of circular dependecies beans may be not fully initialized when they are injected.

It may be useful when bean can be configured to use different collaborators, but in some specific case it need to use itself.

**See also:**

- [3.4.1.3 Dependency resolution process](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#d0e2291)